Is there any way to get a smaller SPI clock speed specifically to only one SPI slave?
I have 3 modules connected by SPI through an ATMEGA328P MCU as shown in the circuit and I have some doubts over the clock speed of the bus.
I have a 8Mhz clock on the MCU which I am assuming sets the SPI clock speed, this is then connected to the CLK pins of all 3 modules which consists of an ADC, CAN transceiver and an IMU. I just have 3 points I need abit more clarity on.

Is the IMU buffered correctly? The enable pins are grounded so it's constantly high but it's to ensure the level shifting as the max input voltage level of the IMU is rated lower
Is it correct to have a clock for the CAN trx aswell? The datasheet shows an example in which it does (page 5) but that's used to externally supply the clock for the MCU, since I already have one for the MCU, can I omit this from the CAN trx or is it needed in addition to the CLK input from the Bus
The 8MHz falls within the max frequency range of the CAN trx and IMU (10MHz and 24MHz respectively) however, the max clock frequency of the ADC is only 2MHz at 5V supply.
Is there a way to step down the SPI clock frequency just for the ADC only? I am aware of clock dividers using the MCU, however I don't want to set the whole SPI CLK Bus to such a low frequency just for the ADC, I'd rather divide it only for the ADC and leave the bus as 8Mhz.

I have come across some slightly different but applicable solutions however I wanted to see if there any good recommendations before I commit to one.


Have you read the AVR data sheet how the SPI clock works and how to set the frequency?

yes, I had a look at the relationship between SCK and the oscillator clock frequency and it can be configured to divide frequency by 4 to get that 2MHz but I assume that'll affect the IMU and CAN trx?

What kind of framework you are using? plain AVR bare metal or Arduino? For Arduino, SPISettings object allows you to have different SPI clock speed for each SPI slaves you are communication with. For AVR bare metal, you could do the same for configuring the register for each communication accordingly.

The resolution of the attached schematic is low and hard to read to read some of the text. Suggest edit the question to include a more readable schematic.

You need to read the AVR data sheet. It explains how to select the SPI clock.
If you want you can freely change the clock at any time you want, so if you want different bus clocks for different chips, you are free to do so.
However your bus is missing the chip selects for the chips so it won't work.
